# Oracle SQL Developer add a column that match another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not sure how to look for that question, but right now im studying sql and in one of my homework, the question is

Show the name, the job and the grade or each worker.

but the thing is theres no such thing as a grade in the existing table.

```
JOB         GRADE 

CLERK       A   
ANALYST     B   
SALESMAN    C   
MANAGER     D   
PRESIDENT   E   
AUTRES      F
```

heres what I want to look like.
what would be the best way to add the column grade and match the letter to the already existing job?
Should I use alter table or I can simply do it with a where ? PLZ help I wanna get ready for my exam next week.

THANK YOU FROM A NOOB

```
SELECT ENAME, job
from emp
```

Comment: You should drop your current table and then import the CSV structure which has both names and grades correlated with each other.

Comment: As we don't know which tables you have nor which columns they contain, it is difficult to assist.

Comment: Presumably you have `grade` in another table and have to somehow match between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether i understood the problem at your hand clearly and below are my understanding

1. You have a table say Employee with 2 columns ename and job.
2. Job column has job name as well as grade with space delimited.
3. The requirement is to display name, job_name,grade in output.

You can use below sql
Select ename,substr(job,1,instr(job,' ')-1) Job_name, substr(job,instr(job,' ')+1) Grade from Employee;

If your requirement is to add new Grade column to table then

1. Alter table to add new column named Grade.
2. Run a update statement to update Grade column based on Job column using "substr" method mentioned in "insert" statement.

Comment: sorry my english is not that great but yeah thats exactly the command I was looking for thank you very much sir